# SQL query ORDER BY with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table. The first with the information of subscribers :

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| id |    first_name    |   last_name  |     mail      |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |       Jean       |    Bono      | jean@bono.com |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 2  |       Paul       |     Dodu     | paule@dodu.com|
--------------------------------------------------------
```

The second with custom fields :

```
------------------------------------------------------
| id | subscriber_id | custom_field_id |   value     |
------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |       1       |        1        | Photographer  |
------------------------------------------------------
| 2  |       1       |        2        | 00000000    |
------------------------------------------------------
| 3  |       2       |        1        | Journalism|
------------------------------------------------------
| 4  |       2       |        2        | 00000000    |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to orderby my subscribers by value where id = 1 or by string value (not int).

For example, first, all "Journalism", secondly all "Photographer"

Here is my SQL query (test) :

```
SELECT sub.*, cf.* 
FROM subscribers AS sub 
JOIN subscriber_custom_field AS cf 
ON cf.subscriber_id = sub.id 
WHERE sub.status = 'subscribed' 
ORDER BY cf.value
```

But this SQL query bug cause mix phone number and string ...

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: It's unclear what order you want. Please explain again what this means: _by value where id = 1 or by string value (not int)._

Comment: Post some more sample data and your expected result.

Comment: Also, you allude to different data types in the same column. I'm assuming you mean it's a `VARCHAR(##)` typed column in which you have a variety of different characters?

Comment: Edited with 2 examples

Comment: what is the output of this query ? what you expected to be ? post both as tables

Comment: My query return first phone and secondly type by alphabetical.. This is not what i want. I just need to order by type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order by custom_field_id = 1 value, then you have to add the WHERE condition on that field, but you will only link the row with custom field = 1:

```
SELECT sub.*, cf.value as type
FROM subscribers AS sub 
JOIN subscriber_custom_field AS cf 
ON cf.subscriber_id = sub.id 
WHERE sub.status = 'subscribed' 
AND cf.custom_field_id = 1
ORDER BY cf.value
```

if you need to select also the other custom fields, I think you have to fully change your SQL, transforming rows in columns using subqueries, otherwise you will obtain one row  for every custom field:

```
SELECT sub.*, 
       (SELECT cf.value FROM subscriber_custom_field WHERE cf.subscriber_id = subscriber_id AND custom_field_id = 1) AS type,
       (SELECT cf.value FROM subscriber_custom_field WHERE cf.subscriber_id = subscriber_id AND custom_field_id = 2 LIMIT 1) AS phone
FROM subscribers AS sub 
JOIN subscriber_custom_field AS cf 
ON cf.subscriber_id = sub.id 
WHERE sub.status = 'subscribed' 
ORDER BY (SELECT cf.value FROM subscriber_custom_field WHERE cf.subscriber_id = subscriber_id AND custom_field_id = 1)
```

Comment: Good but phone number duplicate in type column.

Comment: I don't understand your comment

Comment: Your query create type and phone column. In phone column, it works perfectly but in type column, i have phone numbers too for certain row :)

Comment: I added LIMIT 1 to get only the first one telephone number. If you want  more numbers you can use LIMIT and OFFSET to get X numbers for your X fields

Comment: They can have only one phone number.  I dont know why entry are duplicate in phone or type. For example i have 000000 in type column and the same in phone column. Or i have Journalism in type and phone colum